# What would be the right regex to capture Dutch postal code with some data 'dirtiness'?

Tags: python, regex

I'm having trouble extracting some data properly and into a SQL db, which i'm hoping someone can help with.
The data is scraped from a website and represents Dutch postal codes and cities

The official Dutch postal codes are composed of 4 digits, a space in between, and a 2 capital letter addition.
For example

```
1234 AA
or
5523 ZB
```

The website combines that with the name of the city in one HTML string.
In other words this is what it looks like ideally:

```
1234 AA Amsterdam
```

The first problem that pops up is that the websites allows users to ignore the addition when plugging in a postal code

```
1234 Amsterdam
```

And the second problem is that some of the cities have names that do not begin with a standard Capital letter:

```
5555 AD 's-Hertogenbosch
or
2244 's-Gravenzande
```

I'm essentially trying to split everything, regardless of what special conditions pop up

What i would like to get in the end is each entry separated into 3 parts
The postal 4 digit code, the postal addition (if any), and the name of the city (including the weird symbols)

For example:
Column 1:

> 5555

Column 2:

> AD or null

Column 3:

> 's-Hertogenbosch

I'm fairly new to Regex, so the only thing i could come up with was

```
r"^([^(a-z)]*).*"g
```

which admittedly is terrible.

Any help on the answer or resources that might help me get to one would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use 3 groups to match 4 digits, then optionally 2 uppercase chars and capture the rest in the last group.

```
\b(?P<digit>\d{4})(?: (?P<addition>[A-Z]{2}))? (?P<city>\S.*)
```

The pattern matches:

- `\b` A word boundary
- `(?P<digit>\d{4})` Capture 4 digits
- `(?: (?P<addition>[A-Z]{2}))?` Optionally match a space and capture 2 uppercase chars A-Z
- `(?P<city>\S.*)` Capture a space, a non whitespace char and the rest of the line

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/AxuQ53/1)

For example

```
import re

pattern = r"\b(?P<digit>\d{4})(?: (?P<addition>[A-Z]{2}))? (?P<city>\S.*)"

s = ("1234 AA 5523 ZB\n"
            "1234 AA Amsterdam\n"
            "1234 Amsterdam\n"
            "5555 AD 's-Hertogenbosch\n"
            "2244 's-Gravenzande")

print([m.groupdict() for m in re.finditer(pattern, s)])
```

Output

```
[{'addition': 'AA', 'city': '5523 ZB', 'digit': '1234'},
 {'addition': 'AA', 'city': 'Amsterdam', 'digit': '1234'},
 {'addition': None, 'city': 'Amsterdam', 'digit': '1234'},
 {'addition': 'AD', 'city': "'s-Hertogenbosch", 'digit': '5555'},
 {'addition': None, 'city': "'s-Gravenzande", 'digit': '2244'}]
```

Comment: Hi! Thank you very much, this is the perfect solution! I would upvote, but i do not have 15 reputation yet, so i will come back to upvote both solutions once i have that.

Comment: And thank you for explaining step-by-step how the meaning of each part of the regex, i am so very grateful!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this can help you, I have tested it a little bit with the list data.
I split x on spaces and then check if the second part has 2 capital letters. with the regex pattern [A-Z]{2}.
[A-Z] Means any capital letter, and {2} means that exactly 2 of those character must be found.

But in AAA also 2 of capital letters can be found.

The regex function search returns a Match object when a match has been found and otherwise None. If you turn it into a boolean with bool(), that's either True or False. This way you can add the check on the length with the len-function to it.

```
import re

data = ['1234 AA Amsterdam', '1234 Amsterdam',
        '1234 Den Haag', '1234 AB Den Haag',
        "1234 AA 's Gravenhage", "1234 AA 's-Gravenhage",
        "1234 's Gravenhage", "1234 's-Gravenhage",
        "1234 De Bilt", '1234 AA De Bilt']

for x in data:
    y = x.split(' ')
    col1 = y[0]
    if bool(re.search('[A-Z]{2}',y[1])) and len(y[1])==2:
        col2 = y[1]
        col3 = ' '.join(y[2:])
    else:
        col2 = None
        col3 = ' '.join(y[1:])
    
    
    print(x)
    print(col1)
    print(col2)
    print(col3)
    print('----')
```

I tested the pattern with:

```
import re

tests = ['AX', 'Ax', 'ax', 'aX', 'AAA']
for test in tests:
    print(bool(re.search('[A-Z]{2}',test)) and len(test)==2)
```

This is a nice summary for regex in Python:
https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_regex.asp

Comment: Thank you very much for your swift reply! I'll check out the link, and i will let you know as soon as i test out whether your solution works. Again, thank you very much for the link!

Comment: Hi nessuno, FYI, your solution worked, but i chose the one from 'The fourth bird', because it was slightly more condensed. If i could choose 2 solutions, i would have! Thanks again!